# Buildroot OpenGL Capable Backend

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, buildroot

I'm trying to configure QT 5 through buildroot and some options are not available with the message `requires an OpenGL-capable backend`.  I'm using buildroot 2013.08-rc1 but the same message comes up with 2013.05.

I'm targeting x86_64 core2 platform and I can't find any options to select OpenGL backend (or OpenGL anything actually).

How can I enable OpenGL backend in buildroot?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL backend should be provided by Mesa. However, the Mesa packaging as of 2013.08 is not really great, and there are patches pending to improve it. See http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2013-September/079070.html. Hopefully those patches will make their way soon in mainline Buildroot. Your feedback about them would be very useful.